# Склеивание строк в Си без помощи функций

Tags: c, строки, компилятор

Наткнулся на такую особенность. При выполеннии:

```
printf("HEllo ""World");
```

Почему этот код склеивает 2 строковые константы? Это специальный синтаксис компилятора(я использую gcc) или это просто неочевидная причуда синтаксиса си?

Comment: Это **очевидная причуда** (и она описана в ISO стандарте). Cудя по [этому опиаснию](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/gcc/Incompatibilities.html) очень похоже, что она была в языке всегда

Comment: Почему - потому что так в стандарте. Зачем - чтобы можно было длинную строку на несколько строк кода разбить, например: https://www.ideone.com/DagSQi